# how to auto calculate values

Tags: google-sheets

I'm new to Google Sheets and I need help.

I want to create a "calculator" working on that base:

- I enter a number in a case for example A3
- It will take that number and subtract 50% of the value in the case B1 to this value (A3).
- And then subtract that value to the number in A1.

So it will be: A1 - (A3-50% of B1) and then the case A3 will auto clean for the next operation.

I don't know if it is possible so I'm asking you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to calculate it you need: 

```
=A1-A3-B1*50%
```

to ensure no errors, final formula would be: 

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1);
        ISNUMBER(B1);
        ISNUMBER(A3)); A1-A3-B1*50%; )
```

and for clearing **A3** you can use this script assigned to the button so you can clear **A3** with a click:

```
function moveValuesOnly1() { var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
                             var source = ss.getRange("Sheet1!A2");
                             source.copyTo(ss.getRange("Sheet1!A3"), 
                             {contentsOnly: true}); }
```

**demo spreadsheet: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19KYmvgkXYfD2LWeZWCECj0BYZtZjguHHoWQvkXIcirU/edit#gid=0)**

[image: 1]

Comment: Okay ! Thank you very much it is working ! :D 

One more thing please, how can I do to set if negatif then it is set to 0 ?

Comment: @Fyrens what do you mean by that? pls explain

Comment: I edited my post, I want the formula making negatives numbers to be changed to 0

Comment: Hmmm I think i'll be more clear. 

I wanted with this formula to calculate the remaining HP of a monster after an attack. So the formula is HP - (attack - 50% monster DEF). But the problem I got now is if I put a too high DEF to the monster the formula will go crazy and put negatives numbers. I want to make if monster DEF is twice or more superior to the attack then it will do no damage.

Comment: I see... try: `=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1),
        ISNUMBER(B1),
        ISNUMBER(A3)), IF((A1-A3-B1*50%)<0,"0",A1-A3-B1*50%), )`  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19KYmvgkXYfD2LWeZWCECj0BYZtZjguHHoWQvkXIcirU/edit#gid=1310009789

Comment: Grrr... Your formula is right on your sheet but in mine it's popping an error :
- "Error of analysis of formula"
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IdrXycxyZqKXPmz2906R-ORZ4JgQc_nreU8cPqZX3Pc/edit?usp=sharing